# What is the difference between Perfecto Mobile and Mobile Labs Device Connect?

Tags: testing, mobile, ios-ui-automation

I need to know the difference between Mobile Labs Device Connect and Perfecto Mobile. I don't see much links stating [image]

is there any other differences? Kindly suggest me which one is the best cloud based testing tool.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are many differences between the 2 tools and vendors
1) Perfecto is the leading tool vendor around continuous quality solutions for mobile apps. It backs the solution with a robust mobile quality lab which offers various cloud models (Private Hosted or on premise, Public (top 100 devices always on!), and local devices connected (No hardware required).
2) Perfecto offers open APIs and large set of connection to leading tools (Selenium, Appium, Calabash, HP UFT, Microsoft, IBM, CA, Jmeter, Neotys)
3) Perfecto offers end to end life cycles solutions from manual, automation, performance and monitoring with easy scripting which works on multiple platforms and runs in parallel (in opposed to the MobileLabs only UFT solution which required serial execution)
4) Perfecto offers selenium remote webdriver solution for selenium users DIRECTLY from within the Eclipse IDE (this is the only solution in the market offering cloud connection from eclipse for selenium development). No evidence!! for mobile labs selenium solution

Thanks